# Google Photo API not returning photos for current date

Tags: google-apis-explorer

I'm trying to get photos uploaded to google photos. API does not return photos uploaded on current (today) date.
Original code is written in C#. To isolate the issue I also tried using 'Try this API' feature.
And still Can't get photos of current date. It works when I try to get photos of previous date.

```
HTTP Request : POST https://photoslibrary.googleapis.com/v1/mediaItems:search

{"filters":{"dateFilter":{"dates":[{"day":2,"month":2,"year":2022}]}}}
```

Comment: +1 I think this issue is related to incorrect metadata on the photo (as if I edit the date/time on the photo it'll show in the api results) - but the API should fall back to upload date (as described)

I raised this bug https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/264112025